# How to locate the source file of a subroutine call when debugging a complex CPAN distribution?

Tags: perl, debugging, tk-toolkit

I am trying to debug a [`Tk`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/Tk.pod) program for a while now. The problem seems to be with a `deiconify()` call from a top level window, however I am not able to locate the source file where the `deiconify()` sub is defined. Here is a made-up example just to illustrate what I mean:

**test.pl**:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new( -title => "Main Window" );
$mw->Label(-text => "Debugging", -font => "Times 20")->pack( );
$mw->Button(
    -text    => 'Quit',
    -command => sub { exit },
)->pack;
$mw->Button(
    -text    => 'Show window',
    -command => \&show_window,
)->pack;

my $tl = $mw->Toplevel( -title => "Toplevel 1" );
$tl->Button(
    -text    => 'Quit',
    -command => sub { exit },
)->pack;
$tl->withdraw();
MainLoop;

sub show_window {
    #$DB::single = 1;
    $tl->deiconify();  # <--- Where is this sub defined??
    $tl->raise();
}
```

I first tried to grep the distribution for the sub name<sup>1</sup>:

- `find . -name '*.pm' -exec grep -Hn deiconify {} \;`
- `find . -name '*.xs' -exec grep -Hn deiconify {} \;`
- `find . -name '*.al' -exec grep -Hn deiconify {} \;`
- `find . -name '*.h' -exec grep -Hn deiconify {} \;`

Then I tried to run the script under the debugger

```
perl -d test.pl
```

and set a breakpoint just before the call to `$tl->deiconify()` (see above). When I pressed `s` at the breakpoint

```
  DB<1> s
Tk::Submethods::CODE(0x56245540c658)(/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/site_perl/5.24.1/x86_64-linux/Tk/Submethods.pm:37):
37:      *{$package.'::'.$sub} = sub { shift->$fn($sub,@_) };
```

it shows the line where `deiconify()` was defined as anonymous subroutine ( Line 37 of `Tk::Submethods` ), but when I press `s` again to step into the anonymous subroutine, it just step over it and returns to line 32 in `test.pl`.

I suspect the method must be defined in `Tk::wm` somehow (since it is related to the Window manager) maybe by the auto load mechanism or by dynaloader?

**Footnotes**

<sub>1. The commands was run from the toplevel directory of the Tk distribution. To set it up, run this first:</sub>

```
 cpan -g Tk
 tar zxvf Tk-804.033.tar.gz
 cd Tk-804.033
```

Comment: That line is being shown because it's the code for the `deiconify` method: it is converted into a call to the method named by `$fn` that passes `$sub` (presumably the string `"deiconify"`) as the first parameter. It's presumably XS code if the debugger isn't showing it. What is in `$fn` at that point?

Comment: @Borodin `$fn` is equal to  `wm` as far as I can see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grepping the source a little more liberally (specifically including `*.c` files) finds the string `This procedure is invoked to process the "wm deiconify" Tcl command` in the file `pTk/mTk/win/tkWinWm.c`. It's in a comment introducing the C function `WmDeiconifyCmd`, which certainly looks like it's the actual implementation of that functionality.

I haven't bothered to look into exactly how the Tk module XS code exposes that C function to the Perl level, but if that's what you're really interested in, you now know the endpoints and just have to fill in the middle :-)

Once the function is exposed to the Perl level, the line in `Tk::Submethods` that you quote above is clearly where it gets injected into the appropriate symbol table so it can be called via `$tl->deiconify()`.